# Increment a date in a specific condition

Tags: php, mysql

I’m working on a project and I’m front of this situation :

I parse a file and get values in order to fill a database.

My file could be resume like that :

```
xxxxxxx date=2014-04-26 xxxxxx  (the first line)
Action1 xxxxxx time=12:00:00
Action2 xxxxxx time=12:05:00
```

My Mysql Table :

```
Action varchar 
Time   Datetime
```

I will receive a new file every 5 min and save Action and DateTime ( I need to use the Date from the first line) in my table.

So the problem which could appear is this one :

```
xxxxxxx date=2014-04-26 xxxxxx  (the first line)
Action1 xxxxxx time=23:57:00
Action2 xxxxxx time=00:02:00
```

Indeed, at 00:00:02 the Date will not be correct.

But next time that will be okay because I will have :

```
xxxxxxx date=2014-04-27 xxxxxx  (the first line)
Action1 xxxxxx time=00:02:00
Action2 xxxxxx time=00:07:00
```

Someone have an idea of what i could do to solve this kind of situation ?

Thanks in advance

Ps: I'm coding in PHP

Comment: Sorry it is unclear. What exactly is the issue? Are you having problems comparing the times to see if end time is before start time? Also is this being done in the mysql or in the PHP itself? Please include some of your code.

Comment: your file is a text file ?

Comment: Yes it's a text file. I will edit my Post to make a better explanation

Comment: Is your issue on how to load this format?  Or is the issue on how to process the data after it is loaded to get the right date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have to be guaranteed that `'time='` values are in ascending order, and that the second line in the file (with the `'time='`) is actually a time on the date value represented in the `'date='` from the preceding line.

---

I'd approach it like this:

From the line that has `'date='`, keep that value (in a variable) so it's available when you process the next line.

On the next line, use that saved `'date='` value, and the `'time='` from the current line, and combine those to make the DATEIME for that line.  Save the `'date='` and `'time='` component values (in variables) so those values are available when you process the next line in the file.

When you process the next line, compute the duration between the `'date='` and `'time='` of the previous line (saved in variables) with the same `'date='` value along with the `'time='` value from the current (new) line.

If the duration is greater than or equal to zero, then assume it's the same date. (Use the saved `'date='` value and the new `'time='` value to create the DATETIME to assign to that record.)

If the duration is less than zero (negative), then you can assume the `'date='` portion has rolled over to the next day, so increment the saved `date=` value by one day. Combine the newly incremented `'date='` value with the `'time='` value from that line, to create the DATETIME to be assigned to that record.

Repeat that for each subsequent line, saving the `'date='` and `'time='` components of the DATETIME assigned to that line. Compute the duration, any time it comes up negative, increment the saved `'date='` value by 1.

That's the approach I would use.

(I think you'll probably need to do a reset of the `'time='` save variables, set it to 00:00:00 when you encounter the next `'date='` line in the file, so the computation of the duration will be positive.)

In a more general problem, there's a corner case of the duration being over 24 hours, but there's no good way to detect that from the data shown from the file.